How to disable continuous grab in edit mode?
I've disabled continuous grab in the input section of the preferences, but in edit mode, when using loop cut the cursor behaves like the option is still on.
It's even more weird that the loop cut tool behaves like that only when using shortcut. When I chose tool from left side list, it works normal.
What can I do to stop loop cut from trying to overlap over edges of the current window?

The feature to turn off continuous grab for the Loop Cut tool is not available.
Continuous grab will turn off in edit mode with the setting turned off in preferences, but for every tool except the Loop Cut tool.

So only rebuilding modified version of blender can solve the issue :( I've started digging in the source code, for now found editmesh_loopcut.c but I'm not sure if its correct place to start investigation

Is this really that important? I wouldn't suggest trying to modify blender if it's not that important (waste too much time).

Unfortunately continuous grab is bugged (or x11 mouse grab), either way it launching my mouse pointer into space when I accidentally move it off screen

Maybe try and find a way to fix it rather then trying to turn it off

For now I just need some easy solution so disabling it is the way, but when I find some spare time I'll try to find why it's behaving like that and maybe I'll manage to fix it, cos continuous grab is nice feature to have.

I found two solutions to this problem:
Easy one is to run Blender in debug mode:
blender --debug--all

It disables continuous grab
Little bit more work is to edit ./source/blender/windowmanager/intern/wm_cursors.c function WM_cursor_grab_enable and slap return statement at the beginning,
It will suppress continuous grab entirely.
